# I want to know what the order of execution is for this code w.r.t algorithm for the following code:

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization

I need to know order of execution for my following code:

```
For(j=1; j<n;j++)
   For(k=1; k<15;k++)
      For(l=5; l<n; l++)
      {
         Do_something_constant();
      }
      ...
      ...
```

Options are:

1. O(n)
2. O(n^3)
3. O(n^2 log n)
4. O(n^2 log n)
5. O(n^2)

Please also provide logical reason of the correct option

Comment: What do you think the answer is?

Comment: 1st option but logically it should be 2nd option that's why i am asking here

Comment: SO is not a homework completion site. If you're not able to complete your assignment, ask your instructor for additional help.

Comment: It is not homework "Ken white", it's just curiosity about the correct asnwer

Comment: Come on guys, It is just a question about the optimization, I am professional myself not a student and inhancing my skill toward optimization but confused about these type of R & D

Comment: Should be 5 though, it's two nested loops that take about `n` steps (the middle loop has a constant number of steps and can be ignored).

Comment: Oh Harold, I think you are right coz I did not consider the middle loop has constant number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When in doubt, work from the inside out!"

You have these loops:

```
For(j=1; j<n;j++) {
   For(k=1; k<15;k++) {
      For(l=5; l<n; l++) {
         Do_something_constant();
      }
   }
}
```

Let's start with that inner loop. Each iteration does O(1) work, and there are Θ(n) total loop iterations. We can then replace this loop to get

```
For(j=1; j<n;j++) {
   For(k=1; k<15;k++) {
      Do Θ(n) work
   }
}
```

That inner loop does Θ(n) work 14 times, which is also Θ(n) total work. Remember - big-Θ notation eats constant factors! So now we have

```
For(j=1; j<n;j++) {
   Do Θ(n) work
}
```

This does Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) total work, since it does Θ(n) work  Θ(n) times. So the runtime will be Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

To answer your original question - since the runtime is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), answers 2, 3, 4, and 5 are all correct because each of those upper-bound the runtime. The "best" answer would be answer 5, O(n<sup>2</sup>), since that most tightly bounds the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically have 3 loops nested that preform an operation in O(1) time. The cost of each loop is: (N-1) steps for the first loop, 14 steps for the second loop and (N - 5) for the third loop.

Your time complexity function will look something like this: T(N) = O(N^2). The reason begin that you are allowed to leave out all constants because they will not make a difference for a very large N. (N-1)*(N-5)*15 => leave out consts and you get N^2.

It's the 5th answer hope this helps..